# Mongo not sorting when using EMongoCriteria with MongoDate

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm having some difficulties to select the last entry I posted into my Mongo Collection. This is an example of what an object in my collection looks like:

```
{"category":1,"date:
{"sec":1356521350,"usec":0},"content":"Test Content","_id":
{"$id":"50dadf8639f992c83f000003"}}
```

Now, I want to sort on the field date and I am trying to do so by using the following functionality (by using the Yii-MongoDB-Suite):

```
$oCriteria = new EMongoCriteria;
$oCriteria->sort('date', EMongoCriteria::SORT_DESC);

$oOjbect = ObjectModel::model()->find($oCriteria);
```

Now, instead of returning the object which has the lastest date, it returns me the first object I entered in the collection.

I literally have no clue about what might be going wrong. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to pass a PHP array to `sort()`, so what you actually need is:

```
$oCriteria = new EMongoCriteria;
$oCriteria->sort(array('date', EMongoCriteria::SORT_DESC));

$oOjbect = ObjectModel::model()->find($oCriteria);
```